# Functions that trigger errors based on the reporting level in PHP

Tags: php, error-handling, bitwise-operators

This is a silly question, but I can't seem to wrap my head around the bit mask testing associated with completing this:

Given I create a bunch of generalized functions to extend PHP's function base:

```
/**
 *
 * @param string $path
 * @return array
 */
function load_array($path){
    $path = path_file($path);
    if(null === $path){
        // trigger error when appropriate
        return array();
    }
    return ((Array) require($path));
}
```

<sub>`path_file()` is another function in the library, just assume it to be `realpath()`</sub>

What I'd like to do, is trigger errors according to the current running environment's reporting level. Given this would be a *notice*, should I simply test:

```
if(error_reporting() <= E_USER_NOTICE){ /***/ }
```

That doesn't seem right.

Comment: It works the other way round. You just generate the notice, and the error handler ignores it when that level is disabled. Or why did you want to approach it this way?

Comment: Thanks @mario - I always go the long (*read, wrong*) way around. You're certainly correct, in that I apparently didn't want to approach it this way, yet did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (error_reporting() & E_USER_NOTICE) {
   ...
}
```

would only trigger if the E_USER_NOTICE flag has been enabled in error_reporting, using the bit-wise AND operation.

If you pretend that the error_reporting flag is only 8 bits, and the USER_NOTICE flag is at bit 4, then you're doing:

```
  00001000  <--- e_user_notice
  10101111  <--- some fake error_reporting bitmask
& --------
  00001000  <-- e_user_notice is enabled. It's non-zero, so evaluates to 'true' in PHP.
```

Comment: Thanks @Marc B - That's the direction I was figuring :) Would simply `E_NOTICE` be appropriate here; I figure not since `trigger_error()` is going to throw a `E_USER_*`